# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule, add_rewrite_tag, empty query variables

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with rewrite rules in WordPress.
What I want is url like this:

```
     example.com/postname/mini/minipostname
```

For example:

```
     example.com/destiny/mini/new-tests
```

When I use something like this:

```
     example.com/destiny/?mini=new-tests
```

It works properly.
I search a lot of websites, forums, blogs and others to find how to do this. Finally I get this code:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%minipost%', '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/mini/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?postname=$matches[1]&minipost=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

    // flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
  $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

  if ( ! isset( $rules['^([^/]*)/mini/([^/]*)/?$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
  }
}
```

And it seems rewrite rule and rewrite tag is add properly because when I use following code to print list rewrite tags and rewrite rules

```
function getRewriteRules() {
    global $wp_rewrite; // Global WP_Rewrite class object
    return $wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules();
}
function getRewriteTags() {
    global $wp_rewrite; // Global WP_Rewrite class object
    return $wp_rewrite->rewritecode ;
}
```

I get this for rewrite rules: http://wklej.to/ffTRo/text

And this for rewrite tags: http://wklej.to/W6DOe/text

Futhermore when i type link like this:

```
    example.com/destiny/mini/new-tests
```

It seems that my rewrite rule catch this url, because it shows my default page(not /destiny/ which is what I want).. And when I type something like this:

```
    example.com/destiny/not-mini/new-tests
```

I get 404 error: Page not found.

So the problem is that I don't get post content "destiny" only content of default page.
It seems to me that the variables are empty or it can be something else..

I hope I have described my problem as far as reasonably.

Thanks in advence.

### Edit:

I found an error in my code. I used to name of variable "postname" when i change it to "name" everything started to work.

Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Solved. Wrong name of variable.

Comment: Then please answer you own Question, so it is marked as solved.